# Deployment Strategy for deploying multiple serverless services in one Pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a multiple serverless services in one directory. Each of the services have their own serverless yaml. My directory is as follows. What is the recommended way of deploying such project structure? Is it possible to have a parent serverless yaml to deploy all other serverless.yamls?

[image]

What is the recommended way to deploy these services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there aren't any official serverless tools to deploy multiple services like this. I ended up writing a small bash script to do it. You could use something like:

```
for service in $(find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name serverless.yml -exec dirname {} \;)
do
    cd $service
    npm install
    sls deploy
    cd -
done
```